# How to tune pattern for a given infill density

Tags: ultimaker-cura, infill

Obviously the density and pattern are strictly related but seems values aren't tuned automatically according the combination of various patterns and if I change the infill density Cura chooses automatically only 2 the patterns:

- always ***grid*** for lower densities *<=25 % infill*
- always ***lines*** for higher densities *>25 % infill*

If I change the pattern to something different, I get a warning message

> "This setting is normally calculated, but it currently has an absolute
> value set."

Each pattern has [specific vantages](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/7115/20123) that are useful according the situation, how should I properly configure the combination infill density and infill pattern to get optimal vantage without just wasting time for more intricated patterns?

E.g.
Considering densities ***20 %***, ***40 %***, ***60 %*** and ***triangle*** (best perpendicular resistance), ***cubic*** (best transverse resistance) and ***gyroid*** (best all around) pattern, I would get the specific vantage of each of these patterns at all densities or after a certain level, they haven't any sense?

Comment: The infill density depends on the object you are slicing. E.g. if it has a large flat top you make sure to get enough support to prevent the "roof"/top surface from collapsing (in combination with enough top layers). If the object is a pyramid for instance, you don't need much infill. I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve with this question?

Comment: @0scar "depends on the object" is implicit in the last part of question where I mention the resistance  peculiarity of mentioned patterns, and  the type of mechanical stress to which it is subjected during use